# Can not verify signature value with certificate java

Tags: java, x509certificate, signature

I have soap webservice. To validate messages we use signature with certificate.

When I get message and validate it with client certificate it pass.
Then I sign data by our private key certificate with this code

```
signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "SunRsaSign");
byte[] dataToSign = someXMLNodeString.getBytes();
PrivateKey privateKey = SignatureUtil.getPrivateKeyForCertificate(
"JKS", "keystorefile", "keystorepass".toCharArray(),
"keydomain", "keydomainpass".toCharArray());
signatureValue = SignatureUtil.sign(dataToSign, signature, privateKey);

public static PrivateKey getPrivateKeyForCertificate(
        String keyStoreAlgorithm, String keyStoreName, char[] keystorePass,
        String alias, char[] keyPassword) {
    KeyStore ks = null;
    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreAlgorithm);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    FileInputStream ksfis = null;
    try {
        ksfis = new FileInputStream(keyStoreName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } 
    BufferedInputStream ksbufin = new BufferedInputStream(ksfis);  

    try {
        ks.load(ksbufin, keystorePass);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if(null != ksbufin) {
            try {
                ksbufin.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    PrivateKey priv = null;
    try {
        priv = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, keyPassword);
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return priv;
}

public static byte[] sign(byte[] data, Signature signature, PrivateKey privateKey) throws InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
    //Create a Signature object and initialize it with the private key
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    // Update and sign the data
    signature.update(data);

    //Now that all the data to be signed has been read in, 
    //generate a signature for it
    return signature.sign();
}
```

But when client validate my signature by my given certificate, it fails.
I generated my certificate with these commands

```
keytool -genkey -alias keydomain -keysize 1024 -keyalg RSA -keystore keystorefile

keytool -export -alias keydomain -sigalg SHA1withRSA -keystore .keystorefile -file keydomain.cer -rfc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I had similar problem with Java 1.6 and  I solved it this way.

If you are using standard JDK 1.6 you must download the unrestricted policy files for the Sun JCE if you want the provider to work properly.

The policy files can be found at the same place as the JDK download.

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jce_policy-6-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer

OR

You can simply copy (overwrite) these two files
1: local_policy.jar
2: US_export_policy.jar

into directory:--> JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am trying this now, but why this happens?

Comment: It always fails on this line  byte[] decrypted = RSACore.rsa(sigBytes, publicKey); at RSASignature class

Comment: whats the exception?are public/private keys valid for the certificate? Whats the development environment? Otherwise if you are using windows platform and .pfx /p12 certificates you can load them directly without using "KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");"

Comment: also have a look at have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunRsaSignProvider for SunMSCAPI/SunRsaSign, 
 and finally check if the securityprovider is listed correctly in java.security? i.e. "security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign"

Answer (score 0):

Found problem; it was this line

```
byte[] dataToSign = someXMLNodeString.getBytes();
```

This was wrong method to get byte[] from string object.
You need to stream this string and get bytes from it.